# RequireJS - Unsure how to compile to a single file correctly

Tags: requirejs

Im trying to compile two js files --- main.js and cookies.js -- into one file.

```
    -/
     |-main.js
     |-cookie.js
     |-require.js
     |-main-built.js
     |-build.js
```

main.js holds the script logic and depends/requires cookie.js.

Without require.js if I load cookie.js first and then main.js everything works great. ie:

```
    <script src="cookie.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
```

This works fine for development but I need one final js file for production.

I started trying to use require.js (http://requirejs.org/)

```
        <script data-main="main-built.js" src="require.js"></script>
```

where main-built.js is the single file output result of running:

```
    node r.js -o build.js
```

My build file is setup as follows:

```
    ({
      include: ["cookiejs","requirejs"],
      baseUrl: '.',
      paths: {
      'cookiejs': 'cookie',
      'requirejs': 'require'
    },
      name:"main",
      out: "main-built.js",
    })
```

"main" from the build file pulls in main.js,
"require" pulls in require.js,
"cookie" pulls in cookie.js.

**Problem**
When the final compiled file is executed, the cookie functions are not defined. Specifically, since cookie.js handles cookie interaction the error is:

```
    "Uncaught ReferenceError: cookie is not defined"
```

I can see the cookie.js code is actually copied into main-built.js so I think it's a matter of how to tell require.js that main.js is dependent on cookie.js and have the compiler reorder the execution of the code in the final main-built file but really Im grasping at straws on how to tell require.js how to do that.

***What Ive Tried***

- Including and excluding require.js in the build file and didnt see any difference.
- Using "deps" instead of "include" in the build file --- I did not notice a difference
- Various uglify build options

Comment: Have a loot at [shim](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) config

Comment: Thanks Vishwanath - the cookie.js file that is an dependency is setup to use an AMD loader if present, it appears that the shim config is for older scripts that dont use "define()" to declare the modular value. This is defined as cookie.

Comment: You missed using the shim for dependency configuration. I will add that in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since your main depends on the cookiejs. You have to define this relationship through requirejs configurations. Ideally these dependencies should be defined in the dependent file like following.

main.js

```
define(['cookie'], function(){
});
```

You can also define these dependency with files you wont control  (not the case here ) with shim.

```
({
      include: ["cookiejs","requirejs"],
      baseUrl: '.',
      paths: {
      'cookiejs': 'cookie',
      'requirejs': 'require'
    },
      name:"main",
      out: "main-built.js",
      shim : {
         "main" : ["cookiejs"] //This means main depends on cookie
      }
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Vishwanath. I actually tried this exact shim addition after your first comment, and have been trying several variations with no luck. as the same browser error is occurring. "cookie is not defined"

Comment: Did you re run the optimizer, cleared your browser cache?

Comment: Yes sir - deleted the built files - cleared the browser cache (though its set not to cache with the console open) - rebuilt the file, reloaded in the browser, and still the same error...

Comment: Sorry for treating you as a noob. Didnt see any other problem, hence asked you if we are on the same lane. Can you keep `uglify : none` and check the content of the built file. Order in which files are getting concatenated.

Comment: No worries - I am new to require.js - and am always learning. I set uglify : none but it appears that it is still concatenating, it seems as though the built file starts with main.js file, then inserts cookie.js, then ends with the remaining main.js file.